# Best practice to access private parent attributes?

Tags: java, oop

Imagine you have two classes, the `Parent` class and the `Child` class which inherit from `Parent`. `Parent` has an Attribute `a` which is set at private, and the child class has a `doSomething()` method which need to access to `a` like :

```
public class Parent {
  private Attriute a;
  public Parent(Attribute a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(Attribute a) {
    super(a);
  }
  public void doSomething() {
    // Need to access to a here
  }
}
```

**My question is** : is there a best way to access to `a` from `Child` ? I have few ideas of how to proceed :

- Set visibility of `a` at `protected` in `Parent` but then `a` would be accessible and modifiable evrywhere in the package.
- Create a protected getter in `Parent` of `a` but it would also be accessible evrywhere in the package.
- Create a new private `Attribute` field in the `Child` class and save `a` into it in the constructor. Like this the 'new a' attribute would be only accessible from `Child` and it would be the same object than the `Parent` one but it would also 'duplicated' `a` in both classes.

But I don't know which one is the best one, maybe none of these is, so HELP !!

Comment: ["*Hiding internal state and requiring all interaction to be performed through an object's methods is known as data encapsulation — a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

Comment: use getters and setters. you can put logic in the getter/setter to restrict it's accessibility

Comment: @Michael if only that were true - but it's not. In Java, `protected` gives access to the package _as well as_ to subclasses.

Comment: @davmac Shows how often I use implementation inheritance... :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, in Java, to give access to a member to subclasses without also granting it to all classes in the same package.

Just add a getter method for the field, and make it `protected`. This gives more access than you might prefer, but it's usually acceptable.

If encapsulation is critical, you may be able to move the class into its package and prevent allowing access to non-subclasses in this way.

Comment: Or move the sensitive classes into their own package.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236759/5872281) is maybe what you are looking for.

Create protected method that returns the private attribute, and a restriction so only subclass can get the attribute.

```
public class Parent {
    private Attribute a;
    public Parent(Attribute a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    protected Attribute getA() throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if(!getClass().isAssignableFrom(
        Class.forName(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()))) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException(
                "This method can be accessed by subclass only");
        }
        return a;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(Attribute a) {
        super(a);
    }
    public void doSomething() throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Attribute a = getA();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't get the downvote.
What is wrong with my answer?